# how to use function return value in @pytest.mark.parametrize

Tags: python, pytest

I try to learn how to use pytest.mark.parametrize in my test and found one of example like following.

```
import pytest
@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_input,expected", [ ("3+5",8), ("2+4",6), ("6*9",42), return_param])
def test_eval(test_input, expected):
    assert eval(test_input) == expected
```

However, how can i replace **3+5**, **2+4**, **6*9** with some function return value? like **return_param**

```
import pytest
@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_input,expected", [ ("3+5",8), ("2+4",6), ("6*9",42), return_param])
def test_eval(test_input, expected):
    assert eval(test_input) == expected


def return_param(sef):
    return 7*8, 56
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems straightforward:

```
import pytest

def return_param():
    return "7*8", 56

@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_input,expected", [
    ("3+5", 8),
    ("2+4",6),
    ("6*9",42),
    return_param(),
])
def test_eval(test_input, expected):
    assert eval(test_input) == expected
```

Comment: what if the return_param is under setup_calss? like def setup_class(cls): def return_param():

Answer (score 0):

As per function return value is concern,you can use the return value.
But as you said that the return method will be in the setup class,instead of adding an extra return_param(), add your return logic in setup class itself.

Note:-- The return value from setup_class will be in generator/instance type.